# Cheap / Simple Audio Streaming Device

Tags: audio, streaming

I was looking into setting up a bunch of Apple Airport Express devices (the old 802.11g models) around my house so that I could stream music to any room.... however these are a bit more expensive then I was hoping (around $50-60) or a used one.  Are there any other good, inexpensive options out there for streaming audio wirelessly around the house?

I'm fine with them all playing the same thing, I don't need separate "zones".  Also it would be great if they could just stream what ever happens to be playing on the host computer (Windows 7 in my case)... so basically I could just play audio from any application and it would be heard from each device.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two current options, and one that appears to be no longer available (but you might be able to find it somewhere or perhaps Ebay)

[Linksys WMB54G Wireless-G Music Bridge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E5E6KG) - $75.  Not sure if this is expandable (i.e. you can have multiple endpoint units).

[Creative Labs Xmod Wireless Music System with X-Fi Technology 70SB083000004](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QW9DPU) ($56.99 for a base station + single receiver) - this one is expandable beyond a single receiver unit, and you can purchase additional receiver units separately, though I can't seem to find any on Amazon at the moment.

[Radio Shack 2.4GHz Audio Link with USB Connection](http://www.radioshack.com/pwr/product-reviews/Other/RadioShack/p/2464773-2-4GHz-Audio-Link-with-USB-Connection.html) - not sure how much these are (can't find a price online), nor am I certain that you can expand them past a single receiver unit, but you might want to investigate it... if you have a Radio Shack (ahem, I mean "The Shack") location nearby, maybe they have some stashed away in a back room or on the clearance table.

Sorry I can't be of more help, but this might be a starting point.  Googling "wireless music streaming" or "wireless music system" or some such might be helpful as well.

Comment: The Linksys unit is actually available for around $25 IIRC, but PLEASE DO NOT BUY IT IF YOU VALUE YOUR SANITY.  Seriously, it's terrible.  I suggest springing for the Apple product.

Answer (score 1):

These days the go-to option for multi-room streaming on the cheap is [Google Chromecast Audio](https://www.google.com/chromecast/audio/) at about 35$ a pop. Can do grouping on rooms and is supported by a wide range of apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you may need: Belkin Music Receiver.

[http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F8Z492TTP-Bluetooth-Music-Receiver/dp/B0047T79VS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047T79VS)

Read about that sound quality drops at small distances.