# Setup for streaming sound from laptop to amp (RCA connector) via wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, audio-streaming

I'd like to use my quality speakers as wireless speakers for my laptop, i.e. get all sound output of my laptop to my amplifier without any cables, preferably without having to plug anything into the laptop. The laptop is running Windows 7 64-bit. The amp has [RCA sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector). The wireless network is just a standard home setup (802.11n), so some configuration on the side of the router is possible.

Criteria: good reception quality, affordability, optimally no extra wifi (like with an Airport Express, but feel free to suggest just this solution, if it works).

What setups could I consider?

---

There are similar questions here, but apart from not being up-to-date, they're asking for something slightly different:

- [Cheap / Simple Audio Streaming Device](https://superuser.com/questions/41160/cheap-simple-audio-streaming-device) -- asking for several rooms / reception stations
- [How to stream music from notebook to speakers via wi-fi?](https://superuser.com/questions/277175/how-to-stream-music-from-notebook-to-speakers-via-wi-fi) -- asking about streaming *music* only

Comment: Is bluetooth an option?

Comment: @CharlieRB: Not really, I'd have to use a USB bluetooth dongle, which I usually don't :/